# Installshield Prompt for Multiple Destinations on One Dialog

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installscript

Using InstallShield 2012 spring and wanting to add another file location dialog on the SdAskDestPath2 dialog but not sure how to do so.
 I previously tried to just create a custom dialog (lots of Googling and searching the InstallShield help) by: cloning the original dialog, changing the new dialog's ResourceID, then creating a CustomDialog.rul which included the script out of SdAskDestPath2 but couldn't get that to work.

So many question is simply how do I wire up more than one browsing control on the same dialog in InstallScript? or what am doing wrong with the custom dialog.